# Left eigenvector equation

Tags: linear-algebra

So on wolphram alpha, they define the left eigenvector equation as
$$\pmb{v}A = \lambda\pmb{v} \iff A^T\pmb{v}^T = \lambda\pmb{v}^T \iff (A^T-\lambda\mathbb I)\pmb{v}^T = 0$$

So when we solve for the eigenvector, once we find the eigenvalue, we plug into

$$
(A^T-\lambda \mathbb I) \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

Technically, this definition of the eigenvector equation below is the same right? since $\lambda$ is a scalar, $\lambda\pmb{v} = \pmb{v}\lambda$, so 
$$\pmb{v}A = \pmb{v}\lambda \iff \pmb{v}(A-\lambda\mathbb I) = 0$$

So if we found the eigenvalue for above equation, we can solve for left eigenvalue by then doing

$$
(x, y, z)(A-\lambda\mathbb I) = 0
$$

So is it possible to find left eigenvector without taking transpose of $A$ like this?

Seems like very basic question I am very unconfident when it comes to linear algebra...

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what your question is. Are you asking if $vA=\lambda v\iff (A^T-\lambda I)v^T=0$? (In which case the answer is yes.)

Comment: hi i edited my question, I myself wasn't clear about what I was confused with, i am now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector problem is typically defined via the right eigenvectors. That means for a column vector $x$ is called right eigenvector of a matrix $A$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ if
$$Ax=\lambda x$$
This setting is then explored thoroughly and one can find the eigenvectors by solving the equation that you stated above $(A-\lambda \mathbb{I})x = 0$.

To transition to the left eigenvectors one can observe by your first line, that the left eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ are simply the right eigenvectors of the transposed matrix $A^T$. This then extends all results found for the right eigenvectors to the left eigenvectors as well.

So, yes you can solve the equation $x^T(A-\lambda \mathcal{I})=0$ as well to find the eigenvectors, but it is more convenient for most analysis to use the results for the right eigenvectors.

That is why one usually takes the transpose of the matrix for the analysis of the left eigenvalue/eigenvector problem.

Comment: thank you! makes sense